# Why is my program returning the same permutations multiple times?

Tags: python, duplicates, permutation

I have a simple code which I am using to try and get all combinations of 4 nucleotide bases, but only as sets of 3 because 3 nucleotides make up a codon.  I basically need to generate all possible permutations that can be made by the 4 bases a, c, t and g, and put them in chunks of three, however at first the program seemed to work, and then as I looked at the result I realized it was repeating the permutations 5 times.

I only need all permutations once and I am not sure how to change my code to get this result.  I am also very new to Python so I would really appreciate simple talk and jargon in any answers, thank you!

This is the code:

```
import itertools

bases = ['a','c','t','g']
for L in range(0, len(bases)+1):
  for subset in itertools.permutations(bases, 3):
    print(subset)
```

And the result I get looks right, but I just don't want it repeated 5 times:

```
('a', 'c', 't')
('a', 'c', 'g')
('a', 't', 'c').....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling it to do it five times with that first `for L in range(0, len(bases)+1):` line.

Without that it works fine.

```
import itertools

bases = ['a','c','t','g']
for subset in itertools.permutations(bases, 3):
  print(subset)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `for L in range(0, len(bases)+1)` is looping 5 times, giving you repeted permutations.

You can just remove that line:

```
import itertools

bases = ['a','c','t','g']
for subset in itertools.permutations(bases, 3):
    print(subset)
```